# Conflict between two Javascript on the same js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

As per title, I am a bit new to the javascript coding, and I writing a website in html and css and javascript, this two script are for showing the full menu and the other for a draggable responsive slider carousel. They fight each other, obviously the first one that is loaded works, the other doesn't. Here the two script, what I do wrong, it's really appreciated an help, thanks.
Edit: the error in the console said this:
**main.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children') at main.js:97:37 (anonymous) @ main.js:97**
The line is this: **let carouselChildren = [...carousel.children];**

```
//Fullscreen Menu
/////////////////
const menu = document.querySelector("#fullMenu");
const hamburger= document.querySelector(".ham");
const close= document.querySelector(".closebutton");


function toggleMenu() {
if (menu.classList.contains("showMenu")) {   menu.classList.remove("showMenu");
} else {
menu.classList.add("showMenu");
}
}

hamburger.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
close.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//Draggable Carousel Slider
/////////////////////////////////////////////
let carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper i");
let carouselChildren = [...carousel.children];
let wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

//getting card width
let cardWidth = carousel.querySelector(".card").offsetWidth;
let isDragging = false,
  startX,
  startScrollLeft,
  timeoutId;

//getting number of cards can fit in carousel at once
let cardsPerView = Math.round(carousel.offsetWidth / cardWidth);

//inserting copied few last cards to beggining of carousel for infinite scrolling
carouselChildren
  .slice(-cardsPerView)
  .reverse()
  .forEach((card) => {
    carousel.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", card.outerHTML);
  });

//inserting copied few first cards to end of the carousel for infinite scrolling
carouselChildren.slice(0, cardsPerView).forEach((card) => {
  carousel.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", card.outerHTML);
});

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //if the clicked button id is left scrolling carousel towards left by card width else towards right by card width
    carousel.scrollLeft += btn.id == "left" ? -cardWidth : cardWidth;
  });
});

let dragStart = (e) => {
  isDragging = true;

  carousel.classList.add("dragging");

  //recording initial cursor and scroll position
  startX = e.pageX;
  startScrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft;
};

let dragging = (e) => {
  //returning here if the isDragging value is false
  if (!isDragging) return;

  //scrolling carousel according to mouse cursor
  carousel.scrollLeft = startScrollLeft - (e.pageX - startX);
};

let dragStop = () => {
  isDragging = false;

  carousel.classList.remove("dragging");
};
carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
carousel.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
carousel.addEventListener("scroll", infiniteScroll);
```

Comment: did you check console for errors?

Comment: I suggest to put those separate parts in a self-executing function (wrap it in `(function(){ ... }();`). This prevents conflicts in variable names.

Comment: thanks, guys,. I try to wrap them, but the console tell me always this error:
main.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')
    at main.js:97:37
(anonymous) @ main.js:97

Comment: Well put that error in the question, that would help people find the issue for you. What is at line 97 in main.js? Chances are that you have to wait until lthe DOM is loaded.

Comment: this is at line 97: let carouselChildren = [...carousel.children];

Comment: what do you get when you add `console.log(carousel)` before that line? because if you get `null` or `undefined` in the console, that could indicate that the element `.carousel` doesn't exist at the time of execution as @peter said earlier.

Comment: later on today I would also reccommend looking up how the debugger works in JavaScript - it will help you a lot with these issues in the future

Comment: I'll try to make updates, let me the time to rewrite everything with this precious tips that you guys give to me and I'll let you know if it works. One things Peter, the wrap function, creates a sort of isolated function that could not interfere whit other functions?? thanks a lot btw

Comment: Yes the self-executing function prevents that you accidentally use a variable from another part of the script. I found it helpful as well. Next you should probably wait [until the document is ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: guys, I put everything together and seems to be working just fine. Thanks a lot. If in future I have some other problem on this website I think I continuing to populate this comments, it is ok?? Thanks again, have a nice day.